# how to partition?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a Windows 7 compatible Partition Manager!](https://superuser.com/questions/60057/looking-for-a-windows-7-compatible-partition-manager)

hi! I have a windows 7 OS 64 bit mode...I want to run ansys 12 on it but I have the 32 bit version...now I want to install a parallel OS (win xp probably) but i do not know how to partition my Hard drive..it is currently partitioned into two drives (c drive-40GB and d drive-450GB)... windows 7 is in C drive...how do I partition my D drive into further two drives without loss/transfer of all data that i have stored in it?

Comment: I would recommend you get "virtualbox" and install windowsXP _within_ windows 7. This is far simpler than a multi-boot option imho.

Comment: Try RJFalconer comment solution. If the program fails inside VirtualBox then do dual boot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Disk Management (via "Computer Management" in Control Panel) to adjust partition sizes. You do not necessarily need to reformat a partition just to resize it.

A full description (with pictures) can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/).

[image: Shrink image]

Answer (score 1):

Your challenge is that Windows does not like it when you install an older version over a newer version, even with the partitioning. This is even more important with how Vista and Windows 7 write to the boot sector.

Even if you get Windows XP installed on the second partition, you will be left with an unusable install of Windows 7 until you repair it (which may affect the XP boot.ini file).

Best recommendation: on Windows 7 Professional and higher, you can install a virtual Windows XP Mode. Check it out.

Comment: if you do not have Professional or higher there are many other third party applications which will allow you to create and run custom virtual computers from within Windows (like RJFalconer commented). you would then be able to install pretty much any OS you want to that.

Comment: Nice tip, @Xantec. My reasoning is that there is no need for an additional XP licence if you use the Virtual XP route.

Comment: right...so I will be able to run ansys 12 on this virtual windows XP mode? and will I be able to transfer files from my regular OS (windows 7) to the virtual OS(XP)?